# Mail one liner to check if null before sending

Tags: shell, email, mail-command

I'm trying to modify a script which emails a user group the contents of a directory. The modification I'm looking for is to check the script below to see if it has valid output before sending.

The script is:

`cd $foo/bar && ls | mail -s "Filenames in the \$foo/bar Directory" john.smith@who.com`

I want to test if the file is null before sending this email, as this will go on three dozen servers and many to the same person/people, so I don't want to send a bunch of blank emails (which is the status quo).

I have looked at other similar questions, but none of them quite scratch the itch. This one is closest:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169612/how-can-i-write-a-shell-script-that-will-email-me-a-file-if-the-file-is-not-empt

but is for a file attached, which won't work. Also, `man mail` returns a `-E` flag that is supposed to perform the content check, but I've played with it and my version doesn't seem to support the `-E` option (which is not something that can readily be changed). I get an error `mail: invalid option -- E`.

Any help would be appreciated. It doesn't have to be a one liner, but that sure would help!

EDIT - I need the directories to be dismissed in the output check, if this is possible! I did not clarify this originally, but if $foo/bar has a directory of `/errors` can this be avoided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could trying testing with `wc -l`, something like:

```
cd $foo/bar && [ `ls | wc -l` -gt 0 ] && ls | mail
```

Comment: And, of course, you should always use the actual full paths of all commands in your actual script.

Comment: The problem with using the full path is that on each server it's slightly different, but the shortcut is identical on all of them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've done this before with a setup similar to:

```
out=`cd $foo/bar && ls` ; [[ -n "$out" ]] && echo "$out" | mail -s "Filenames in the \$foo/bar Directory" john.smith@who.com
```